Einstein Studio training model doesn't end
I tried to reproduice this tutorial in a partner org DTCO with data cloud. I followed the same step but the data I used where directly inserted in salesforce. Then retrieved as DLO with Data Stream -> DMO
I followed the same step in Einstein Studio but event after 72h, the model is still training (no error displayed).
Is there some point I should double check or this is normal to take a lot of time to train a model in a non production sandbox ?

I raised a case and apparently this is a known issue that affect sandboxes and production environments. The only workaround is to retry a build if it don't finish for a long time.
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000zgzfKAAQ/~
